# Unable to refresh a CalendarView with UpdateLayout() [UWP]

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml, calendarview

In my UWP app, I'm trying to refresh the density bars on a `calendarview` if the user clicks a button, the problem is that, although `calendarView.UpdateLayout();` should re-run the `CalendarViewDayItemChanging` event, it runs only when the `CalendarView` is loaded the first time. Am I doing something wrong?

```
 public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            densityColors.Add(Colors.Green); 
        }

      private void CalendarView_CalendarViewDayItemChanging(CalendarView sender, CalendarViewDayItemChangingEventArgs args)
            {
                item = args.Item;
                if (item < DateTimeOffset.Now)
                {
                    item.SetDensityColors(densityColors);
                }

            }

            private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
            {
                densityColors[0]=Colors.Blue;
                calendarView.UpdateLayout();
            }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`UpdateLayout` won't do anything here since there's no *layout* update and `CalendarViewDayItemChanging` is only triggered when you move to another calendar view.

In your case, you just need to manually locate all the `CalendarViewDayItems` and update their colors on the existing view.

First, create a little `Children` extension methods to help retrieve all the children of the same type.

```
public static class Helper
{
    public static List<FrameworkElement> Children(this DependencyObject parent)
    {
        var list = new List<FrameworkElement>();

        for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parent); i++)
        {
            var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parent, i);

            if (child is FrameworkElement)
            {
                list.Add(child as FrameworkElement);
            }

            list.AddRange(Children(child));
        }

        return list;
    }
}
```

Then, simply call it in your button click handler to get all `CalendarViewDayItem`s, loop them through and set each's color accordingly.

```
var dayItems = calendarView.Children().OfType<CalendarViewDayItem>();
foreach (var dayItem in dayItems)
{
    dayItem.SetDensityColors(densityColors);
}
```

Note you don't need to worry about new `CalendarViewDayItem`s coming into view as they will be handled by your `CalendarView_CalendarViewDayItemChanging` callback.