# How to read only the CalendarView control in UWP

Tags: xaml, calendar, uwp, uwp-xaml

On my UWP app, I have added a CalendarView and programmatically selected several dates. Now I want to make it read only to the end user. But the control does not provide such functionality and making IsEnabled = False is not an option.
Please let me know a way of making the control read only.
Thanks.

NOTE: I get this problem with the keyboard. When a user hits enter key or space bar key, Calender changes its view. I want to make it static.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone who's looking for a complete code here it is. All this is thanks to [Justin XL](https://stackoverflow.com/users/231837/justin-xl).

```
static int minOne = -1;
    static int plsOne = 1;
    public static async Task ManipCalenderUserInterface(List<CalendarView> calenders, List<List<DateTime>> datesListByMonth)
    {
        try
        {

                CoreDispatcher coreDispatcher = Window.Current.Dispatcher;
                await Task.Run(async () =>
                {
                    await Task.Delay(1000);
                    //coreDispatcher is required since you're not on the main thread and you can't manip UI from worker threads
                    await coreDispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal,
                        () =>
                        {
                            int cnt = 0;
                            bool cont = false;
                            bool stop = false;
                            //Highlight color. I get it from my resource file
                            SolidColorBrush colorBrush = (SolidColorBrush)Application.Current.Resources["FgBlue1"];

                            //This code wrote to manipulate multiple calenders
                            foreach (var item in calenders)
                            {
                                var dayItems = item.Children().OfType<CalendarViewDayItem>();
                                var firstDayOfMonth = new DateTime(dayItems.Skip(15).First().Date.Year, dayItems.Skip(15).First().Date.Month, plsOne);
                                var lastDayOfMonth = firstDayOfMonth.AddMonths(plsOne).AddDays(minOne);

                                foreach (var dayItem in dayItems)
                                {
                                    var textBlock = dayItem.Children().OfType<TextBlock>().Single();

                                    int dayNum = System.Convert.ToInt32(textBlock.Text);
                                    if (dayNum == 1 && !stop) cont = true;

                                    if (cont && dayNum >= 1 && dayNum <= lastDayOfMonth.Day)
                                    {
                                        textBlock.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
                                        //Bold the today date on this month's calender
                                        if (dayItem.Date == DateTime.Now.Date)
                                        {
                                            textBlock.FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold;
                                        }

                                        //datesListByMonth: contains all the dates need to be highlighted on th calender
                                        if (datesListByMonth[cnt] != null && datesListByMonth[cnt].Contains(dayItem.Date.Date))
                                            dayItem.Background = colorBrush;
                                    }
                                    if (cont && dayNum == lastDayOfMonth.Day)
                                    {
                                        cont = false;
                                        stop = true;
                                    }
                                }
                                cnt++;
                                cont = false;
                                stop = false;
                            }
                        });
                });

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }
```

Comment: You might be able to just create a Task and await on it without using Task.Run I think. :)

Comment: @JustinXL I encounter an issue with this approach. On windows 10 build 10240 it works like a charm but rest of the updated Win 10 OS's calendar will not get refreshed. SO how many times I do the calendar dates change it only shows the initially loaded data. Calendar only get refreshed when comes back to the calendar page from another page. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

Setting `IsEnabled` to `False` is the right way to go. I guess the reason that you don't want to use it is because doing so would dim the whole control. So the real question comes down to - how to disable the control while making its appearance unchanged?

Generally, the appearance of a *disabled* (i.e. `IsEnabled="False"`) control is defined in the `Disabled` state inside its style. In your case though things will get a little bit more complicated because you need to update more than one styles as the `CalendarView` is a complex control.

Here is how it can be done.

First, you need to find the [default style](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt299113.aspx) of the `CalendarView` control and put it inside your `App.xaml`. Then, search for `<VisualState x:Name="Disabled">` and comment out everything within this visual state. There should be **two** of them 'cause the first one is for the *up/down* button and second one is for all the *day of week* text.

Apart from this, you also need to manually update the color of each `CalendarViewDayItem` simply because the `TextBlock` which is used to display the *day number* doesn't live inside its style.

To do this in code, go to my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45736978/unable-to-refresh-a-calendarview-with-updatelayout-uwp/45745493#45745493) and copy over`Children` extension method, then you just need to run the following code in your `Loaded` event. Note you might want to give it a little bit delay so the `Disabled` state is applied properly.

```
Loaded += async (s, e) =>
{
    await Task.Delay(100);
    var dayItems = MyCalendarView.Children().OfType<CalendarViewDayItem>();
    foreach (var dayItem in dayItems)
    {
        var textBlock = dayItem.Children().OfType<TextBlock>().Single();
        textBlock.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
    }
};
```

After doing all this, your `CalendarView` control will now appear just as normal  when it's actually disabled.

Hope this helps!

Comment: It works until I set MyCalendarView.SelectionMode = CalendarViewSelectionMode.Multiple; Then it won't work. Any thoughts?

Comment: I also need a way of ignoring OutOfScopeDayItems. Only the live items need to change its foreground color.

Comment: Did you try re-running the code? You will need to work out which day item is out of scope and then update the color accordingly. If there's no API to tell, check the Foreground color of the text block.

Comment: Thanks. What's the deal with the CalendarViewSelectionMode? Your code only works with CalendarViewSelectionMode not set to multiple.

Comment: Do you update the selection on the fly? If I set it to multiple in xaml, it still works.

Comment: Yes from the code behind I select multiple dates. I see calendar style appears for a second and then disappear. I set the IsEnabled = False on the style itself. So does the SelectionMode = Multiple

Comment: All you need is re-run the code after a short delay. Might need to increase the delay to `200` just to be sure. I tested it and it works.

Comment: Thank you so much. I increased the delay to a 1 second and it works perfectly now. You saved a lot of my time. :) Cheers!

Comment: How do I call Loaded += async (s, e) => event explicitly? On my app calendar will get updated every one minute. So the style will be lost when the calendar gets updated after 1 minute. Any solution?

Comment: Put that piece of code into a Task and rerun it every time you need it.

Comment: Works perfectly. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

You could also try

```
YourCalendarView.IsHitTestVisible = false;
```

or

```
<CalendarView IsHitTestVisible="False" />
```

Comment: This only works with touch. I get this problem with the keyboard. When a user hits enter key or space bar key, Calender changes its view. I want to make it static.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is late, but assuming that you want the user to still be able to select and scroll through months, etc. this is all you should need to do:

```
<CalendarView SelectionMode="Multiple">
    <CalendarView.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="CalendarViewDayItem">
            <Setter Property="IsHitTestVisible"
                    Value="False" />
            <Setter Property="IsTabStop"
                    Value="False" />
        </Style>
    </CalendarView.Resources>
</CalendarView>
```

The `IsHitTestVisible` setter will ensure that the `DayViewItem` cannot be clicked or tapped, and the `IsTabStop` setter prevents keyboard focus on it.

This allows you to keep the full `CalendarView` functionality while simply disabling user date-selection.

Comment: It’s never too late for a correct answer. I’ll do this and let you know how it went. :) Thanks.